# How to show the record in visual force email template as the order they created?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have one custom object ticket in saleforce and visualforce email template that use the ticket custom object as below

```
  <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.E_Ticket_s__r}">
 <tr>
 <td>
  <apex:outputText value="{!cx.Airline__c}" escape="false" /> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
```

it work well but i need the record print in the order of they created.
suppose i have created first 
air cananda thn air india then british airways
and order will be
air cananda
 air india
british airways.

but in email i recieved not in sort order how is possible to sort the record and display in email.As i came to know that custome object have one
Standard Fields Property name "E-Ticket # Name"
which is autonumber.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you place the Tickets into a collection variable within your controller, you can sort them in the SOQL query using *order by*.  Your *apex:repeat* will then display them according to the order of the collection.

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!tickets}">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <apex:outputText value="{!cx.Airline__c}" escape="false" /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</apex:repeat>


// within the controller

public List<E_Ticket_s__c> tickets() {
  List<E_Ticket_s__c> results = new List<E_Ticket_s__c>([
    SELECT Id, Airline__r.CreatedDate, Airline__c
    FROM E_Ticket_s__c
    ORDER BY Airline__r.CreatedDate
  ]);

  return results;
}
```

The only problem is that there is no List method that will allow you to sort a list of sObjects, so if you need to sort outside of SOQL you would need to "roll your own."